# final close failed :file truncated

Tags: c, syntax-error

i am making a programme in c for some reason it is showing this message
 \.\nul  final close failed:file truncated...
it is not a compiler error this is message when i do syntax check..

here's the code..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int T,N,K,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&N);
        scanf("%d",&K);
        int A[N];
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            scanf("%d",&A[j]);
        long int s1=pow(2, N);
    int count,big=0,flag=0;
    for(count=0;count<s1;count++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            if(count&(1<<j))
            {
                flag=(A[j]^K)^flag;
            }
            else if(count==0)
                flag=K;

        }
        if(flag>big)
            big=flag;
    }
    printf("%d\n",big);

    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I can't find the error message has anything to do with your code. What did you use for syntax check? How about a simpler "hello world" code?

Comment: @yu hao   i used syntax check option in dev c...

Comment: Time to reboot, I think.  The message doesn't make much sense; it sounds as if the Dev C environment is confused.  Restart it, or reboot the computer, and see whether the problem is solved.

Comment: before asking the user to enter a value, you should always tell the user the limits and meaning of the value they are to enter.

Comment: any time an input function (scanf) is used, the returned value should always be checked to assure the operation/conversion was successful.

Comment: It would greatly help us to help you if 1) meaningful names were used for variables.  2) some description of what the code is trying to perform were included

Comment: according to my compiler, there is nothing wrong with the syntax of the code.

Comment: cant tell you guys what code it is...it's competetion prob..

Comment: Every source file have to end with a empty line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are failing to flush `stdin` after each use of `scanf` which leaves a `newline` in the input buffer (the result of pressing [enter]), which is then taken as the next value for the following `scanf` call. The fact you have no prompt to enter your values masks the fact that your input requests are being skipped. Add a prompt asking for each piece of data, and either use a loop to extract the `newlines` from the input buffer, or change the `scanf` format string to read and discard the `newline` each time you read input. Note, none of these are perfect solutions. Give the following a try:

```
printf ("\nEnter T: ");
scanf("%d%*c",&T);
for(i=0;i<T;i++)
{
    printf ("\nEnter N: ");
    scanf("%d%*c",&N);
    printf ("\nEnter K: ");
    scanf("%d%*c",&K);
    int A[N];
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
        printf ("\nEnter A[%d]: ", j);
        scanf("%d%*c",&A[j]);
    }
```

By prompting for your input, you will at least be aware when you are skipping over input requests due to the `newline` being taken as your intended input.